# What is the Django query for the below SQL statement?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

There is a simple SQL table with 3 columns: id, sku, last_update
and a very simple SQL statement: SELECT DISTINCT sku FROM product_data ORDER BY last_update ASC

What would be a django view code for the aforesaid SQL statement?

This code:
`q = ProductData.objects.values('sku').distinct().order_by('sku')`
**returns 145 results**

whereas this statement:
`q = ProductData.objects.values('sku').distinct().order_by('last_update')`
**returns over 1000** results

Why is it so? Can someone, please, help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If the query is already ordered, do you really need to order it again in the view?

Comment: It represents a table which sorting is managed by clicking on table headers. So depending on the "sorting state" I either need to have it sorted by an 'sku' or by a 'last_update'. But I'm so much surprised that Django ORM can't handle easily such simple SQL statements. For example, it's way too easier to do this via SQLalchemy...

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, it seems to me that django rightly believes that, to order a view by sku, the sku field must be present in the output, which scuttles your distinct().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first query the result is a list of (`sku`)s, in the second is a list of (`sku`, `last_update`)s, this because any fields included in the `order_by`, are also included in the SQL `SELECT`, thus the distinct is applied to a different set or records, resulting in a different count.

Take a look to the queries Django generates, they should be something like the followings:

Query #1

```py
>>> str(ProductData.objects.values('sku').distinct().order_by('sku'))
'SELECT DISTINCT "yourproject_productdata"."sku" FROM "yourproject_productdata" ORDER BY "yourproject_productdata"."sku" ASC'
```

Query #2

```py
>>> str(ProductData.objects.values('sku').distinct().order_by('last_update'))
'SELECT DISTINCT "yourproject_productdata"."sku", "yourproject_productdata"."last_update" FROM "yourproject_productdata" ORDER BY "yourproject_productdata"."last_update" ASC'
```

This behaviour is described in the [`distinct` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

> Any fields used in an order_by() call are included in the SQL SELECT
>   columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in
>   conjunction with distinct(). If you order by fields from a related
>   model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may
>   make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra
>   columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to
>   support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are
>   being returned.
>
> Similarly, if you use a values() query to restrict the columns
>   selected, the columns used in any order_by() (or default model
>   ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the
>   results.
>
> The moral here is that if you are using distinct() be careful about
>   ordering by related models. Similarly, when using distinct() and
>   values() together, be careful when ordering by fields not in the
>   values() call.

Comment: This is the key phrase which clarifies it all: "any fields included in the order_by, are also included in the SQL SELECT". Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problems, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question